# hidden date insert sql

Tags: html, date, mysqli

When I insert a value through my form, I would like that the date is saved in MySQL datebase. I do not want the user to se it, but I need the dates for a future function, so I can loop through the dates registrered in db.

Do I need to make a hidden input field in my form, and asign it to my select.php, or is there a smart way to do that?

```
<form id="myForm" action="select.php" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="numbervalue" id="numberinput" min="1" max="36">
    <input type="submit" id="sub" Value="Submit">
    <span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

select.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO numbertable(numbers) VALUES(?)");
                    // bind variable: 'd' for digit/tal, 's' for string
                    $stmt->bind_param('d',intval($_POST["numbervalue"]));   // bind

                    // execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) { // tjek om udført:
                    $success = true;
                }

                // luk statement
                $stmt->close();

                // luk connection
                $mysqli->close();   

if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
}

?>
```

response.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include('session.php');

// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';
$pad_left_values = array(0 => 28, 1 => 10, 2 => 47, 3 => 10, 4 => 47, 5 => 10, 6 => 47, 7 => 10, 8 => 47, 9 => 10, 10 => 42, 11 => 42, 12 => 7, 13 => 42, 14 => 7, 15 => 42, 16 => 7, 17 => 42, 18 => 7, 19 => 7, 20 => 42, 21 => 7, 22 => 42, 23 => 7, 24 => 42, 25 => 7, 26 => 42, 27 => 7, 28 => 42, 29 => 42, 30 => 7, 31 => 42, 32 => 7, 33 => 42, 34 => 7, 35 => 42, 36 => 7);
$colorArr = array(0=>"#029002", 1=>"#ff2700", 2=>"#ffaf32", 3=>"#ff2700", 4=>"#ffaf32", 5=>"#ff2700", 6=>"#ffaf32", 7=>"#ff2700", 8=>"#ffaf32", 9=>"#ff2700", 10=>"#ffaf32", 11=>"#ffaf32", 12=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ffaf32", 14=>"#ff2700", 15=>"#ffaf32", 16=>"#ff2700", 17=>"#ffaf32", 18=>"#ff2700", 19=>"#ff2700", 20=>"#ffaf32", 21=>"#ff2700", 22=>"#ffaf32", 23=>"#ff2700", 24=>"#ffaf32", 25=>"#ff2700", 26=>"#ffaf32", 27=>"#ff2700", 28=>"#ffaf32", 29=>"#ffaf32", 30=>"#ff2700", 31=>"#ffaf32", 32=>"#ff2700", 33=>"#ffaf32", 34=>"#ff2700", 35=>"#ffaf32", 36=>"#ff2700");

    // '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT numbers FROM numbertable ORDER BY num_id DESC LIMIT 27;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // gør variabler klar:    
    $number = null;    
    $n_id = null;


    /* bind result variabler */
    $stmt->bind_result($n_id, $number);

    /* fetch values for hver row, her kun 1 row dog: */

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $pad = ($number >= 0 && $number <= 36? $pad_left_values[$number]: $pad_left_values[0]);
        $col = ($number >= 0 && $number <= 36? $colorArr[$number]: $colorArr[0]);

            echo "<li><div style='padding-left: ".$pad."px; color: ".$col."'>$number</div></li>";
    }    

    // luk statement                        
    $stmt->close();

    // luk connection
    $mysqli->close();                   
?>
```

Comment: why does the date have to be in the html? if you want a date added to the record, you don't have to put it into the html, e.g. `insert into foo (datefield) values(now())` will make mysql generate today's date for you without EVER getting it anywhere near the user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the column like numdate as DATETIME

Try this one:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO numbertable(numbers, numdate) VALUES(?, NOW())");
                    // bind variable: 'd' for digit/tal, 's' for string
                    $stmt->bind_param('d',intval($_POST["numbervalue"]));   // bind

                    // execute prepared statement 
                if ($stmt->execute()) { // tjek om udført:
                    $success = true;
                }

                // luk statement
                $stmt->close();

                // luk connection
                $mysqli->close();   

if($success) {
    echo "Insert Succesfull";
} else {
    echo "Failed: " .  $stmt->error;
}

?>
```

***UPDATE***

You try to bind to something not existing.

**response.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
//include('session.php');

// Selecting Database
include 'dbconfic.inc.php';
$pad_left_values = array(0 => 28, 1 => 10, 2 => 47, 3 => 10, 4 => 47, 5 => 10, 6 => 47, 7 => 10, 8 => 47, 9 => 10, 10 => 42, 11 => 42, 12 => 7, 13 => 42, 14 => 7, 15 => 42, 16 => 7, 17 => 42, 18 => 7, 19 => 7, 20 => 42, 21 => 7, 22 => 42, 23 => 7, 24 => 42, 25 => 7, 26 => 42, 27 => 7, 28 => 42, 29 => 42, 30 => 7, 31 => 42, 32 => 7, 33 => 42, 34 => 7, 35 => 42, 36 => 7);
$colorArr = array(0=>"#029002", 1=>"#ff2700", 2=>"#ffaf32", 3=>"#ff2700", 4=>"#ffaf32", 5=>"#ff2700", 6=>"#ffaf32", 7=>"#ff2700", 8=>"#ffaf32", 9=>"#ff2700", 10=>"#ffaf32", 11=>"#ffaf32", 12=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ff2700", 13=>"#ffaf32", 14=>"#ff2700", 15=>"#ffaf32", 16=>"#ff2700", 17=>"#ffaf32", 18=>"#ff2700", 19=>"#ff2700", 20=>"#ffaf32", 21=>"#ff2700", 22=>"#ffaf32", 23=>"#ff2700", 24=>"#ffaf32", 25=>"#ff2700", 26=>"#ffaf32", 27=>"#ff2700", 28=>"#ffaf32", 29=>"#ffaf32", 30=>"#ff2700", 31=>"#ffaf32", 32=>"#ff2700", 33=>"#ffaf32", 34=>"#ff2700", 35=>"#ffaf32", 36=>"#ff2700");

    // '?' er placeholders for variabler
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT num_id, numbers FROM numbertable ORDER BY num_id DESC LIMIT 27;");

    // execute prepared statement 
    $stmt->execute();

    // gør variabler klar:    
    $number = null;    
    $n_id = null;


    /* bind result variabler */
    $stmt->bind_result($n_id, $number);

    /* fetch values for hver row, her kun 1 row dog: */

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $pad = ($number >= 0 && $number <= 36? $pad_left_values[$number]: $pad_left_values[0]);
        $col = ($number >= 0 && $number <= 36? $colorArr[$number]: $colorArr[0]);

            echo "<li><div style='padding-left: ".$pad."px; color: ".$col."'>$number</div></li>";
    }    

    // luk statement                        
    $stmt->close();

    // luk connection
    $mysqli->close();                   
?>
```

Comment: Super that is working. Thank you:) I was reading that it was more problematic when it was DATETIME, instead of just DATE? Just one last question. I also have a response page, where I get my return values from my db. On that page I get now:

Notice: Undefined index: in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/game/response.php

Is it because I addéd a new column in db?

Comment: DATETIME contains the current time, DATE does it not. Please update your question with your response.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I would like that the user is not getting returned the date.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/game/response.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/game/response.php on line 29

Notice: Undefined index: in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/game/response.php on line 30

Comment: Look to the SQL Statement, here you has just one column selected but you try to bind two columns.

Comment: You are really cool Andreas. Thank you a lot. I will just sit and go through the code, so I also learn something from it :-) Best Regards

Comment: Nice to see that I could help you.